# Geting Interdependent Hashmap's Key with Value of another entry

Tags: java, hashmap

My problem here as follows :
I have Map whose entry will be as follows :

1. `Hashmap.put("Requested_value",null);`
2. `Hashmap.put("Value","Requested_value");`

I need to find out what value does Requested_value hold.
Here these map values will be populated from parsed MS word document . 
"Requested_value" value is a drop down value. Based on that value , I have other business logic to carry out. 
Please give suggestions as how to find interdependent values in hashmap. where one entry's key will be another entry's value.

Comment: the `null` value doesn't make things clear.

Comment: Its interdependent based on parsed word document . <br> It has dropdown value in word . Initially it has no value . so value as 'null' . on selecting drop down new value will be populated and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop to traverse the chain of key-value pairs:

```
String value = map.get(initialKey);
while (map.containsKey(value)) {
    value = map.get(value);
}
```

Comment: How does this code gives me dependent key's value ?

Comment: @VijayPatil If I understand your question correctly, you have a chain of key-value pairs where each value is the key of the next pair. This code starts with an initial key and finds all the values of the key-value pairs of the chain. It currently only keeps the final value, but you can easily store all the intermediate values in a List if you need them.